# Energy of a dielectric object in a field

Tags: energy, electrostatics, electric-fields, polarization, dielectric

How can I prove that this equation:

$E = \frac{1}{2 \chi} \int d^{3}x \ |P|^{2} - \int d^{3}x \ P \cdot \mathcal{E}$

Is equivalent to saying that: $P = \chi \mathcal{E}$?

Where $\mathcal{E}$ is the external electric field and $P$ is the polarization of the object.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed I think that I solved it.

Within all possible polarizations (i.e. configurations) that a dielectric object in a field can have, the one that pops up is the one that **minimizes the energy**.

Thus, taking the derivative of the energy with respect to the polarization and setting it to zero, one finds that the polarization must fulfil the relation:

$P = \chi \mathcal{E}$